# Create a multi-language dropdown without Database connection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a country dropdown menu, usually you set the data in the database and call it into the controller and view to get the results as following.

```
                <select name="country" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">{{ trans('global.address.placeholder.country') }}</option>
                    @foreach ($countries as $country)
                        <option value="{{ $country->id }}">{{ $country->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

My question: How to populate dropdown menu values from language `resources` without `Database`. Like defining the values in a file in `resources` folder and call them successfully into `view` based on language used.

Answer (score 0):

`$countries` would contain the result of `trans('countries')`, where `countries` is a file in `lang/{lang}/countries.php`, that returns an array of key/value pairs for each Country, translated as required.

```
$countries = trans('countries');
```

Or, skip definition of `$countries` altogether, and just use `trans()` (or `__()`, depending on Laravel version):

```php
@foreach(trans('countries') AS $key => $label)
<option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $label }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Each file in `/lang/{lang}/countries.php` would simply return an array:

`/lang/en/countries.php`:

```php
<?php
return [
  "canada" => "Canada",
  "us" => "United States of America",
  ...
];
```

`/lang/fr/countries.php`:

```php
<?php
return [
  "canada" => "Canada",
  "us" => "États Unis",
  ...
];
```

And so on and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'll try the code however my related question, how to use it as a dependent dropdown for Country and States in `create()` and `edit()` function when selecting a certain country for example US it will populate the states correspondent to it.

Comment: You'd need another file for `provinces`, or a nested array in `countries`. That being said, if you have a related question, please ask it as a separate question; questions should only deal with a single, concise problem.